# Toggle buttons when click out of popover and button

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

Code here: https://plnkr.co/edit/ysD1JN0ELqu7ACgkkp79?p=preview

I have two buttons. One is "State1" and another is "State2".

In the beginning, it is in "State2" button. Then I click "State2" button, it toggle to "State1" button, also generate popover.

I want to click out of "State1" button and popover, ***then it will change from "State1" button to "State2" button***. I use popover-trigger="outsideClick", but it does not work. Please advise. Thanks

```
<div ng-click="Ctrl.Check = !Ctrl.Check" popover-trigger="outsideClick">
            <a ng-class="{'btn-danger': !Ctrl.Check, 'btn-default': Ctrl.Check }" confirm-link="Ctrl.deleteCurrent(Ctrl.A)" uib-popover="I appeared on focus! Click away and I'll vanish..." popover-trigger="outsideClick" popover-placement="right">
                {{ Ctrl.Check ? 'State1' : 'State2' }}
            </a>
</div>
```

Comment: code for popver-trigger directive?

Comment: @Mayur  
I added, please check. Thanks

Comment: popver-trigger directive is default feature in UI boostrap, just popover-trigger="outsideClick"

Comment: If you can create a plunker or fiddle it would be more helpful since your question is a bit ambiguous @AngularFan

Comment: @Yaser
I did. https://plnkr.co/edit/ysD1JN0ELqu7ACgkkp79?p=preview

Comment: @Mayur
I have plunker for you to check

Comment: @AngularFan here is your solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is the plunker
https://plnkr.co/edit/KXWzDN882fWEByUNzks6?p=preview

What I did

```
      <a 
            ng-class="{'btn-danger': !isOpen, 'btn-default': isOpen }" 
            state-change-capture 
            confirm-link="Ctrl.deleteCurrent(Ctrl.A)" 
            uib-popover="I appeared on focus! Click away and I'll vanish..." 
            popover-trigger="'outsideClick'" 
            popover-is-open="isOpen" 
            ng-click="isOpen = !isOpen"
            popover-placement="right">
                {{ isOpen ? 'State1' : 'State2' }}
      </a>
```

in the controller

```
$scope.isOpen = false;
$scope.$watch('isOpen', function (oldVal, newVal) {
    //just for reference in case you need to know the status of popover
  });
```

added a property for uib-popover known as `popover-is-open="isOpen"`
which tells if the popover is visible or not and based on that set the State 1 or 2

Also if you need to observe it then have added a watch to controller, just in case you need it.

Comment: I delete ng-controller="PopoverDemoCtrl" in <div>, it still works? 
$scope.isOpen = false is this necessary?

Comment: $scope.isOpen = false is necessary to not show popup at first, also to keep that check to state2

Comment: @AngularFan Did the plunker and this solution answer your question?

Comment: I understand your answer. But my case still not working. I am debugging it.

Comment: Because I did not use uib-popover, I have my popover in another template (xxx.html). Any idea about this?

Comment: uib-popover-html - Takes an expression that evaluates to an HTML string. Note that this HTML is not compiled. If compilation is required, please use the uib-popover-template attribute option instead. The user is responsible for ensuring the content is safe to put into the DOM!

Comment: uib-popover-template - A URL representing the location of a template to use for the popover body. Note that the contents of this template need to be wrapped in a tag, e.g., <div></div>.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the `''` in the popover-trigger, and you don't need the first one on the div itself:

```
<div ng-click="Ctrl.Check = !Ctrl.Check">
        <a ng-class="{'btn-danger': !Ctrl.Check, 'btn-default': Ctrl.Check }" confirm-link="Ctrl.deleteCurrent(Ctrl.A)" uib-popover="I appeared on focus! Click away and I'll vanish..." popover-trigger="'outsideClick'" popover-placement="right">
            {{ Ctrl.Check ? 'State1' : 'State2' }}
        </a>
```

Comment: Yes, it hidden popover. But it does not toggle back to "State2" button